# Entity Framework and PostgreSQL: quotation marks issue

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The problem I am facing is around SQL queries in pgAdmin 4.

Entity Framework (including its Core edition) capitalizes the names of tables and columns.

Which means your SQL will then look something like

```
select e."Id", e."Text" from "Entries" e
where e."Text" like '%implicated%'
```

I was googling the way to prevent Entity Framework from capitalizing names but didn't found out much.

Is there a workaround to avoid wrapping table and column names in quotes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try [Column(“lowerCaseolumnName”)]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy done!

Go to `OnModelCreating` method.

You need an extension method (the code is shared below)

```
modelBuilder.NamesToSnakeCase();
```

Create `ModelBuilderExtensions` class and paste the following:

```
public static void NamesToSnakeCase(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // Replace table names
        entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Relational().TableName.ToSnakeCase();

        // Replace column names            
        foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
        {
            property.Relational().ColumnName = property.Name.ToSnakeCase();
        }

        foreach (var key in entity.GetKeys())
        {
            key.Relational().Name = key.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
        }

        foreach (var key in entity.GetForeignKeys())
        {
            key.Relational().Name = key.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
        }

        foreach (var index in entity.GetIndexes())
        {
            index.Relational().Name = index.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see `ToSnakeCase` extension method - here it is in `StringExtensions` class:

```
public static string ToSnakeCase(this string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { return input; }

    var startUnderscores = Regex.Match(input, @"^_+");
    return startUnderscores + Regex.Replace(input, @"([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower();
}
```

Remove the db, recreate migrations, then run `dotnet ef database update` - bingo!

[image]

Comment: this code helped me for my issue with EFCore integration with oracle.

Answer (score 7):

## For EF Core 3 and above

By default postgres saves all table names, column names as lowercase.

Some databases seem to not require any configuration with EF Core in order to map Camel cased names in the application to case insensitive names in the database. For instance with MS SQL Server, you can have the application entities with CamelCased, but then in the database you don't case them and everything works fine.

With Postgres this seems not to be the case and therefore some `configuration` of is required.

[Npgsql recommend](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/table-column-naming.html) this nuget package [EFCore.NamingConventions](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions) which provides similar functionality to @Alex Herman's answer. Although you don't have to invoke the method on every property, you just use it once.

There are two places you can use it

## 1. In your DbContext.cs

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseNpgsql(...)
        .UseLowerCaseNamingConvention();
```

## 2. Or in your Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DilaDbContext>(opt => 
       opt.UseNpgsql(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
           b => b.MigrationsAssembly("NameOfAssembly"))
       .UseLowerCaseNamingConvention() // <======== HERE
   ...
```

[Npgsql.org](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/table-column-naming.html)  says that

> Starting with 3.0.0, you can use the EFCore.NamingConventions plugin to automatically set all your table and column names to snake_case instead:

There are also some other naming conventions included, I used the lowercase naming convention, because that's what I've used most

They offer these conventions

- `UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention`: FullName becomes full_name
- `UseLowerCaseNamingConvention`: FullName becomes fullname
- `UseUpperCaseNamingConvention`: FullName becomes FULLNAME

Probably don't use the uppercase one, as its the uppercase letters in the database objects name that causes the EF config to require the quotes

Comment: also have faced MigrationId renaming issue & got solution from following link: https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions/issues/1

Comment: Intellisaense doesn't work.  Can you atleast type what "using....." did you use?

Comment: @user1034912, I think it would be EFCore.NamingConventions once you have installed it using nuget

Comment: I have an open source project I created using this here https://github.com/max-carroll/dila/blob/master/DilaAPI/DilaAPI/Startup.cs you could have a look and see how I used it, Ill update the answer when I get a chance

Comment: Just install the nuget package ` EFCore.NamingConventions` that should be all you need to do

Comment: What version of EFCore are you using, if its less than 3.0 perhaps that's your problem?

Comment: It would be easier just to remove these quotes - what`DbCommandInterceptor` can do - but for migration tasks (`DbCommandInterceptor` seems not to be functioning for migration script generation) - instead of bringing everything to Camel / Upper / Lower. More safe... I'm still searching the way to do that: with 3rd party solution or own approach... I've tried to use the interceptor inside `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`, but in vain...

Answer (score -5):

Just create your tables and fields using only lowercase simbols.